# Установка cookie и скрытие блока

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужно поставить cookie и скрыть блок:

HTML:

```
<a style="display: block" id="97" href="javascript://" onclick="hidetask('97')">контент</a>
```

JS:

```
function hidetask(id) {
    var ws = new Date();
    ws.setDate(30 + ws.getDate());
    document.cookie = "hide_" + id + "=ok; path=/; expires=" + ws.toGMTString();
    var tohide = document.getElementById(id);
    tohide.style.display = "none";
    alert('ok');
};
```

Всё работает, но не скрывается. с jQuery:

```
function hidetask(id) {
    var ws = new Date();
    ws.setDate(30 + ws.getDate());
    document.cookie = "hide_" + id + "=ok; path=/; expires=" + ws.toGMTString();
    $("#" + id).hide();
    alert('ok');
};
```

То же самое. В чем ошибка?

Comment: jQuery подключен? функция обернута в `$(function() { ... });`?

Comment: обернул саму, Uncaught ReferenceError: hidetask is not defined. вызывается через `onclick="hidetask('<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>')"`

Comment: готово, подправил

Comment: `<a style="display: block" id="97" href="javascript://" onclick="hidetask('97')">контент</a>` написано же

Comment: Ладно, проехали. Несколько странно, что это один и тот же элемент.

Comment: А теперь по поводу самого вопроса: в [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p0u50e0z/) всё прекрасно работает. Исправить код, который работает, достаточно тяжело.